# SQL Query - How to Filter out duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

If i have two accounts (1 & 2) but I am trying to filter accounts that have Apples but not Oranges. How would you do that based off of this data?

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
join accounts a on a.id = p.id
join 
(
  SELECT account
  FROM products p
  join accounts a2 on a2.id = p.id
  WHERE products LIKE '%Apples%'
) a2.id = a.id    
WHERE products NOT LIKE '%Oranges%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query and your sample data are not consistent.  Based on the *data*:

```
select account_num
from t
where product in ('Apples', 'Oranges')
group by account_num
having min(product) = max(product) and min(product) = 'Apples';
```

You can actually simply the `having` clause for your example to:

```
having max(product) = 'Apples'
```

This uses the fact that "Apples" occurs before "Oranges" alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM "YourTableName" 
WHERE Account_# NOT IN (
    SELECT Account_# FROM "TheSameTableNameAsMentionedBefore" 
    WHERE Product = "Oranges"
);
```

It should work. But I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. You mentioned something about 'no duplicates'. I suggest you take a look at DISTINCT.
https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-distinct/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists`

```
select *
from your_table t1
where exists (select 1 
              from your_table t2
              where t2.account_num=t1.account_num and product='Apples')
and not exists (select 1 from 
                your_table t2
                where t2.account_num=t1.account_num and product='Oranges');
```